# How to redirect a user to login page(if not logged in already) to authenticate and back to the same controller to perform the remaining operation?

Tags: spring, security, authentication, redirect

I have the Create-Group functionality where the user clicks a button and fills the form and submits. While submitting, if the user is not logged in then it should redirect to the login page, get him authenticated, and redirect back to the Create-Group controller where the submit Group action is done after authentication. How do I redirect a user to the login controller and back to the same Create-Group Controller to submit the form? I'm using spring-boot-(Java Configs), spring-security-customSuccessHandler, JSP.

I have tried googling many blogs and other stack overflows but didn't get a clear idea.

```
@PostMapping("/group/create") 
    public String singleFileUpload(@RequestParam("title") String title,             @RequestParam("groupDescription") String groupDescription, Model theModel){     



        blah..blah..blah..
        if(currentPrincipalName.equals("anonymousUser")) {
            System.err.println("User admin name is null so redirecting him to the login page");
            theModel.addAttribute("returnToGroup","returnToGroup");

             return "redirect:/showMyLoginPage";

        }else {
            System.err.println("The user logged in is "+currentPrincipalName);
        }

        theGroup.setAdminName(currentPrincipalName);

         etc...etc...
```

Comment: Let me know if additional details are necessary

Comment: Using spring security and thymeleaf you can define what pages must be authorized. By this way Spring itself will manage the redirect behavior when user is not logged in.

Comment: Thanks. I will research on that